# How to add additional Cancel button to the top of the new form?

Tags: design, button

I am creating a custom list. I removed the ribbon at the new form because it was not designed as the site and was ugly. Instead of it I would like to add a cancel button to the top of the page, same as at the bottom by default becuase the form is quite long. How can I do that by adding javascript?

Comment: are you using Infopath? nintex? clean Javascript? 
can you add more details about your form ?

Comment: Using clear Javascript by adding script editor to the site.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. But couple of easiest would be:

1. Create a 'NewItem' form using designer(It gives you a default Save & cancel button both top and bottom)
2. Open the newitem page in seperate window and `Click Gear icon
   ->Choose 'edit  page'` and add below script inside `Content Editor Webpart(CWEP)`

`

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
   $('table.ms-formtable').before("<a href='yoururl' style='padding:10px;float:right;background-color:red;color:#fff;border-radius:5px;'>Cancel</a>")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't edit content editors inside SharePoint Designer, this is a horrible  practice as it don't let the  normal user access the code. 

you have 2 better practices that are 
1.- Create an html file and store in site assets, and then add it to your content link in the content editor web part properties 
2.- place your code in an script editor

Comment: Same thoughts @Erin. If you read my answer correctly I did not say 'Edit' in designer. I said create a new itempage using designer or edit the newitem page in browser(I believe if you know SharePoint using ~gear~ icon is only possible via browser). So understand the answer before you vote for it. You are always allowed to answer on your own..